# GUnicorn + CUDA: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess

Tags: python, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, gunicorn

I am creating an inference service with torch, gunicorn and flask that should use CUDA. To reduce resource requirements, I use the preload option of gunicorn, so the model is shared between the worker processes. However, this leads to an issue with CUDA. The following code snipped shows a minimal reproducing example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import torch

app = Flask('dummy')

model = torch.rand(500)
model = model.to('cuda:0')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def f():
    data = request.get_json()
    x = torch.rand((data['number'], 500))
    x = x.to('cuda:0')
    res = x * model
    return {
        "result": res.sum().item()
    }
```

Starting the server with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 gunicorn -w 3 -b $HOST_IP:8080 --preload run_server:app` lets the service start successfully. However, once doing the first request (`curl -X POST -d '{"number": 1}'`), the worker throws the following error:

```
[2022-06-28 09:42:00,378] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/user/project/run_server.py", line 14, in f
    x = x.to('cuda:0')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 195, in _lazy_init
    "Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. " + msg)
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
```

I load the model in the parent process and it's accessible to each forked worker process. The problem occurs when creating a CUDA-backed tensor in the worker process. This re-initializes the CUDA context in the worker process, which fails because it was already initialized in the parent process. If we set `x = data['number']` and remove `x = x.to('cuda:0')`, the inference succeeds.

Adding `torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` or `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` won't change anything, probably because gunicorn will definitely use `fork` when being started with the `--preload` option.

A solution could be not using the `--preload` option, which leads to multiple copies of the model in memory/GPU. But this is what I am trying to avoid.

Is there any possibility to overcome this issue *without* loading the model separately in each worker process?

Comment: A quick search leads ti this: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#cuda-in-multiprocessing

Comment: Yes, that's basically what the error message also told me. I was hoping, someone knew a trick around this issue, but I assume that there's currently no way around it. In the meantime, we stopped using the preload option, thus having the model in memory multiple times.

Comment: In the provided link you have the workaround to the issue. You have to spawn a new CUDA. System is complaining about sharing the CUDA instance among processes, not about tensor sharing. GPU memory is already shared among processes. So use `spawn` and then you can share tensors (and in many cases models) between processes.

Comment: BTW, IDK how concurrent memory management is handled in GPUs/CUDA hence I'm not sure you have any performance gain by sharing a model between processes. In such case you may create just one process for the model and then communicate with it.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it could save some memory. I'll try to figure out how to do that next week. Currently, we need 4 GB per model (i.e., per process). For three processes, this makes a total of 12 GB of memory for the model alone, which is quite a lot. So, I was hoping to reduce this footprint a bit.

Comment: @Green绿色 Sorry for an unrelated question: where I can find the evidence for "gunicorn will definitely use fork when being started with the `--preload` option"?

Comment: "[Load application code before the worker processes are forked.](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app)": GUnicorn uses fork to create workers, but if using the `--preload`, the application is initialized before the fork and the pre-forked data is shared among the workers. For more details or evidence, we must check the [source code](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Reason for the Error

As correctly stated in the comments by @Newbie, the issue isn't the model itself, but the CUDA context. When new child processes are forked, the parent's memory is shared read-only with the child, but the CUDA context doesn't support this sharing, it must be *copied* to the child. Hence, it reports above-mentioned error.

### `Spawn` instead of `Fork`

To resolve this issue, we have to change the start method for the child processes from `fork` to `spawn` with `multiprocessing.set_start_method`. The following simple example works fine:

```
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp


def f(y):
    y[0] = 1000


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = torch.zeros(1).cuda()
    x.share_memory_()

    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(x,), daemon=True)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print("x =", x.item())
```

When running this code, a second CUDA context is initialized (this can be observed via `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` in a second window), and `f` is executed after the context was initialized completely. After this, `x = 1000.0` is printed on the console, thus, we confirmed that the tensor `x` was successfully shared between the processes.

However, Gunicorn internally uses `os.fork` to start the worker processes, so `multiprocessing.set_start_method` has no influence on Gunicorn's behavior. Consequently, initializing the CUDA context in the root process must be avoided.

### Solution for Gunicorn

In order to share the model among the worker processes, we thus must load the model in one single process and share it with the workers. Luckily, sending a CUDA tensor via a `torch.multiprocessing.Queue` to another process doesn't copy the parameters on the GPU, so we can use those queues for this problem.

```
import time

import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp


def f(q):
    y = q.get()
    y[0] = 1000


def g(q):
    x = torch.zeros(1).cuda()
    x.share_memory_()
    q.put(x)
    q.put(x)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  # this process must live as long as x is in use


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = mp.Queue()
    pf = mp.Process(target=f, args=(queue,), daemon=True)
    pf.start()
    pg = mp.Process(target=g, args=(queue,), daemon=True)
    pg.start()
    pf.join()
    x = queue.get()
    print("x =", x.item())  # Prints x = 1000.0
```

For the Gunicorn server, we can use the same strategy: A model server process loads the model and serves it to each new worker process after its fork. In the `post_fork` hook the worker requests and receives the model from the model server. A Gunicorn configuration could look like this:

```
import logging

from client import request_model
from app import app

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bind = "localhost:8080"
workers = 1
zmq_url = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"


def post_fork(server, worker):
    app.config['MODEL'], app.config['COUNTER'] = request_model(zmq_url)
```

In the `post_fork` hook, we call `request_model` to get a model from the model server and store the model in the configuration of the Flask application. The method `request_model` is defined in my example in the file `client.py` and defined as follows:

```
import logging
import os

from torch.multiprocessing.reductions import ForkingPickler
import zmq


def request_model(zmq_url: str):
    logging.info("Connecting")
    context = zmq.Context()
    with context.socket(zmq.REQ) as socket:
        socket.connect(zmq_url)
        logging.info("Sending request")
        socket.send(ForkingPickler.dumps(os.getpid()))
        logging.info("Waiting for a response")
        model = ForkingPickler.loads(socket.recv())
    logging.info("Got response from object server")
    return model
```

We make use of [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1621) for inter-process communication here because it allows us to reference servers by name/address and to outsource the server code into its own application. `multiprocessing.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Process` apparently [don't work well with Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293644/gunicorn-queue-not-working-after-re-starting-worker/75307381). `multiprocessing.Queue` uses the `ForkingPickler` internally to serialize the objects, and the module `torch.multiprocessing` alters it in a way that Torch data structures can be serialized appropriately and reliably. So, we use this class to serialize our model to send it to the worker processes.

The model is loaded and served in an application that is completely separate from Gunicorn and defined in `server.py`:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import logging

import torch
from torch.multiprocessing.reductions import ForkingPickler
import zmq


def load_model():
    model = torch.nn.Linear(10000, 50000)
    model.cuda()
    model.share_memory()

    counter = torch.zeros(1).cuda()
    counter.share_memory_()
    return model, counter


def share_object(obj, url):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind(url)
    while True:
        logging.info("Waiting for requests on %s", url)
        message = socket.recv()
        logging.info("Got a message from %d", ForkingPickler.loads(message))
        socket.send(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="Serve model")
    parser.add_argument("--listen-address", default="tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info("Loading model")
    model = load_model()
    share_object(model, args.listen_address)
```

For this test, we use a model of about 2GB in size to see an effect on the GPU memory allocation in `nvidia-smi` and a small tensor to verify that the data is actually shared among the processes.

Our sample flask application runs the model with a random input, counts the number of requests and returns both results:

```
from flask import Flask
import torch

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def infer():
    model: torch.nn.Linear = app.config['MODEL']
    counter: torch.Tensor = app.config['COUNTER']
    counter[0] += 1  # not thread-safe
    input_features = torch.rand(model.in_features).cuda()
    return {
        "result": model(input_features).sum().item(),
        "counter": counter.item()
    }
```

### Test

The example can be run as follows:

```
$ python server.py &
INFO:root:Waiting for requests on tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 
$ gunicorn -c config.py app:app
[2023-02-01 16:45:34 +0800] [24113] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-02-01 16:45:34 +0800] [24113] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (24113)
[2023-02-01 16:45:34 +0800] [24113] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-02-01 16:45:34 +0800] [24186] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24186
INFO:root:Connecting
INFO:root:Sending request
INFO:root:Waiting for a response
INFO:root:Got response from object server
```

Using `nvidia-smi`, we can observe that now, two processes are using the GPU, and one of them allocates 2GB more VRAM than the other. Querying the flask application also works as expected:

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:8080
{"counter":1.0,"result":-23.956459045410156} 
$ curl -X POST localhost:8080
{"counter":2.0,"result":-8.161510467529297}
$ curl -X POST localhost:8080
{"counter":3.0,"result":-37.823692321777344}
```

Let's introduce some chaos and terminate our only Gunicorn worker:

```
$ kill 24186
[2023-02-01 18:02:09 +0800] [24186] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24186)
[2023-02-01 18:02:09 +0800] [4196] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4196
INFO:root:Connecting
INFO:root:Sending request
INFO:root:Waiting for a response
INFO:root:Got response from object server
```

It's restarting properly and ready to answer our requests.

### Benefit

Initially, the amount of required VRAM for our service was `(SizeOf(Model) + SizeOf(CUDA context)) * Num(Workers)`. By sharing the weights of the model, we can reduce this by `SizeOf(Model) * (Num(Workers) - 1)` to `SizeOf(Model) + SizeOf(CUDA context) * Num(Workers)`.

### Caveats

The reliability of this approach relies on the single model server process. If that process terminates, not only will newly started workers get stuck, but the models in the existing workers will become unavailable and all workers crash at once. The shared tensors/models are only available as long as the server process is running. Even if the model server and Gunicorn workers are restarted, a short outage is certainly unavoidable. In a production environment, you thus should make sure this server process is kept alive.

Additionally, sharing data among different processes can have side effects. When sharing changeable data, proper locks must be used to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

when I add `import torch. multiprocessing as mp mp.set_start_method('spawn')` and remove `precision=16` this code `trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="gpu", devices=2, max_epochs=2)`workes for me.

Comment: Do you use Gunicorn? As I explained [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308606/2989330), setting `set_start_method("spawn")` does work in general, but not when deploying a model with Gunicorn because Gunicorn uses `os.fork` to create worker processes, which cannot be influenced by the `set_spawn_method` method.

Answer (score -3):

You can use "gevent" instead of gunivorn. I solved this problem by using it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).